# Unique items in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I hope you guys can help me,I have some troubles with dropdownlist.There are duplicates im my selectlist,so I use GroupBy and avoid them this way,but two ActionResult Create classes can't have two identical parametres.And it doesn't work.
Here is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult Create(Flight flight)
{

        var departures = db.Flights.Where(m => m.Departure == flight.Departure)
         .OrderBy(m => m.Departure)
         .Select(i => i.Departure)
         .Distinct();
    ViewBag.Departure = new SelectList(departures);
    ViewBag.CompanyId = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyId", "Name");
    ViewBag.TransportId = new SelectList(db.Transport, "TransportId", "Name");
    return View();
}


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,FlightId,Departure,Destination,Day,DepartureTime,ArrivalTime,Seats,Cost,TransportId,CompanyId")] Flight flight)
{
    try
    {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Flights.Add(flight);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    }
    catch (DataException /* dex */)
    {
        //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
    }
    var departures = db.Flights.Where(m => m.Departure == flight.Departure)
         .OrderBy(m => m.Departure)
         .Select(i => i.Departure)
         .Distinct();
    ViewBag.Departure = new SelectList(departures);
       ViewBag.CompanyId = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyId", "Name", flight.CompanyId);
    ViewBag.TransportId = new SelectList(db.Transport, "TransportId", "Name", flight.TransportId);
    return View(flight);
}
```

As you see I want to have only unique items in my dropdownlist.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Departure", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

If I do this

```
public ActionResult Create(Flight flight)
{

        var departures = db.Flights.Where(m => m.Departure == flight.Departure)
         .OrderBy(m => m.Departure)
         .Select(i => i.Departure)
         .Distinct();
    ViewBag.Departure = new SelectList(departures);
    ViewBag.CompanyId = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyId", "Name");
    ViewBag.TransportId = new SelectList(db.Transport, "TransportId", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

I have an error with identical parameter.

If this way which is obviously wrong.

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {

        ViewBag.CompanyId = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyId", "Name");
        ViewBag.TransportId = new SelectList(db.Transport, "TransportId", "Name");
        return View();
    }
```

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Departure'.

So how I should code it in GET action that it would work?How I should set my Viewbag in GET action?

Comment: Your question is not clear!! What makes you difficult to apply `Distinct` in your first `Create`

Comment: and why are you have 2 different sets of data in `ViewBag.Departure`. IT should be same in both your action methods before returning to the view.

Comment: Also, remember when you do `Distinct` on a non value type (Ex : a property of a complex type, you probably want to implement `EqualsTo`. I still do not understand what you are trying to do. **PLEASE DO NOT ADD CODE TO COMMENTS. ADD IT TO THE ORIGINAL QUESTION**

Comment: Sorry ! I still do not understand! What is `flight.Departure` in your GET action? What is the type of `Departure` in your Flight entity ?

Comment: **I use GroupBy and avoid them** I do not see this in your question! **but two ActionResult Create classes can't have two identical parametres.And it doesn't work**. Sorry ! I am having trouble understanding this. What is your expected behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your razor view code is expecting a ViewBag with name `Departure`. So make sure you set that in your GET action.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var departures = db.Flights.OrderBy(m => m.Departure)
                                                     .Select(i => i.Departure).Distinct();
    ViewBag.Departure = new SelectList(departures);
    ViewBag.CompanyId = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyId", "Name");
    ViewBag.TransportId = new SelectList(db.Transport, "TransportId", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

Assuming you have the below code in your view.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Departure", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This should fix your error "***There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Departure'***."

Assuming you want to show all the unique `Departure` column values from the Flight table. If you want a subset, use a Where clause in your LINQ expression as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much! The thing was in using OrderBy instead of GroupBy,now I get it.And sorry for not quite clear asking

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a couple things wrong here. Your first Create (GET) should not be taking in your flight. It's not being used at all. if you MUST have the flight object to know what kind of departures are available, just take in the flight ID so you can find it in your DB.

As for your list, create a new class that builds select lists. Then from your view, you can call it.

```
public static class SelectListsHelper
{
    public static SelectListsHelper Instance { get; } = new SelectListsHelper();

    public static List<SelectListItem> GetDepartures(long flightId)
    {
        var list = new List<SelectListItem>()

        //Build up your list here.

        return list;
    }
}
```

Call from the view like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Departure, SelectListHelper.Instance.GetDepartures(Model.Id))
```